# Should I anticipate any problems trying to use the same SSL Cert on 2 computers (primary, backup)?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a production machine running IIS6 with a wildcard SSL certificate.  The certificate that was installed is not exportable.

We want to upgrade the system to IIS7.  As part of this venture, we're creating a backup/failover server that will serve the exact same websites - when we take the primary down for upgrade, the secondary will take over.  As such, the secondary *also* needs the SSL certificate.

However, since the certificate was not exportable, this means re-keying it from Go Daddy.

Per http://help.godaddy.com/article/867, I know that by re-keying the certificate the original will stop working.

I'm still pretty new to SSL certificates, so are there any problems I should anticipate when installing the same SSL certificate on 2 different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the certificate is valid for both of them, you should be fine.

Comment: Please elaborate - under what circumstances would a certificate be valid for one machine, but not the other?

Comment: A certificate contains a domain name, list of domain names, or wildcard domain name that it is valid for. For example, a certificate for alpha.domain.com cannot be used on beta.domain.com, but one for *.domain.com can be used on both.

Answer (score 2):

I would re-key the certificate and install it on the secondary machine and make sure that it's exportable.  Then, export the certificate and install it on the existing server.  This ensures that they both have the same exact certificate in place.  Keep a copy of the PFX export file in a safe place in case you need to restore it again later.

Answer (score 0):

What does GoDaddy mean when they say the original cert will be deactivated, without revoking it? And unless the browser checks the CRL, even revoking does nothing ... the browser and web server would still use the cert ok.

Or am I off base?

Back to the real question, in my experience you can use the same cert on multiple web servers as long as you use the same URL to get to it.

EDIT: Ah-ha, I read the GoDaddy site wrong ... "it is not **necessary to request** revocation" ... they do it automatically. My mistake.

Comment: I wondered that too (how it was 'deactivated'), but assumed it true given the statement on that linked page...

Comment: When you "rekey" a certificate using GoDaddy's interface, it is revoked, and another is issued.